# How to extract screen_name from a tweet and use that to get all the past favorites of that user?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to search the tweets, extract the screen_name from the statuses and use that to get the past favorite tweets of that screen_name. Now I donot know how to extract the screen_names from statuses and then how to use to get past favorites. This is my code(the problem is with the last line):

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = '' 
access_secret = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
search_results = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="Ganesh World").items()

for i in search_results:
    print i.text.encode('utf-8')
    print   api.favorites([i.screen_name])
```

It is throwing AttributeError:Status object has no attribute 'screen_name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to waste another API call,
You can fetch it from inner data elements, i.e. from author , and within that from its json like this:

```
for i in search_results:
    print i.author._json['screen_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in search_results:
    print i.text.encode('utf-8')
    user_details = api.get_user(user_id = i.from_user_id)    
    print api.favorites([user_details.screen_name])
```

You are trying to get `screen_name` directly from the tweet. First you should get `id` and then use it to get screen name.

Comment: What is tweet in 2nd last line?

Comment: It is throwing error 'Status' object has no attribute 'from_user_id' in 3rd line of your code(after ignoring what tweet is). I guess we have to do something like i.entities.SomethingToExtractScreenName.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Modified the code. Can you try once again?

Comment: i.from_user_id is throwing error 'Status' object has no attribute 'from_user_id'. 3rd line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do:
    i.user.screen_name